# Define foreign key as well as group foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

Which of the following 2 versions of a schema is more correct (and possibly performant on INSERT)?:

Schema 1:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (vehicle VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE weapon (weapon VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE unit 
    (vehicle VARCHAR REFERENCES vehicle, weapon VARCHAR REFERENCES weapon, PRIMARY KEY(vehicle, weapon));

CREATE TABLE price 
    (price INTEGER, vehicle VARCHAR REFERENCES vehicle, weapon VARCHAR REFERENCES weapon,
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle, weapon) REFERENCES unit (vehicle, weapon));
```

Schema 2:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (vehicle VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE weapon (weapon VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE unit 
    (vehicle VARCHAR REFERENCES vehicle, weapon VARCHAR REFERENCES weapon, PRIMARY KEY(vehicle, weapon));

CREATE TABLE price 
    (price INTEGER, vehicle VARCHAR, weapon VARCHAR, -- removed foreign key constraints on individual columns
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle, weapon) REFERENCES unit (vehicle, weapon));
```

My question is whether it is  good practice to also set the individual foreign key constraints here, or if this results in redundant extra integrity checks on INSERT, as the integrity is already going to be checked at the FOREIGN KEY line.  Or perhaps Postgresql is sophisticated in that it will not result in an extra integrity check, but the schema is clearer if the individual foreign keys are explicitly indicated too?

Comment: I agree the 1st version is unnecessary cumbersome. But I think the 2nd is also. What does the attribute Price refer to (ie Price of what). As structures it appears as if it's intersection data the the M:M resolution. If so move it to unit and get rid of price table.

Answer (score 1):

The second version is what I would likely use, mainly because the foreign key constraints in `price` on `vehicle` and `weapon` are redundant.  They are redundant because the `unit` table already performs these checks, and `price` references the `unit` table.  It is the responsibility of the `unit` table to perform these checks.